# Asynchronous didn't work in multiple Task

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I want to make my program working asynchronously, but i got stuck in some part.

This is my main Sub, this will call Function ProsesData in loop, i got problem in my  ProsesData Function.

```
Module Main
 Sub Main()
    Proses()
End Sub
  Async Function Proses() As Task
    Dim busOtomasi As New BusOtomasiSample
    Dim dtProses As New DataTable
    Dim strMessage As String = ""
    Try

        Dim tasks = New List(Of Task(Of Tuple(Of String, DataRow)))()
        dtProses = busOtomasi.GetListProsesNotDone(strConn)
        If dtProses.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To dtProses.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim k = i
                tasks.Add(ProsesData(dtProses.Rows(k), dtProses.Rows(k)("isAktelFinishProses")))
            Next
            For Each taskAwait In Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
                If taskAwait.Item1 = "success" Then
                    ExportExcel(taskAwait.Item2)
                    strMessage = "Data Otomasi Sample " & IIf(IsDBNull(taskAwait.Item2("param_strKcpCd")), taskAwait.Item2("param_strKcuCd").ToString, taskAwait.Item2("param_strKcpCd").ToString) & " Sudah Selesai Di Proses." & vbCrLf & "Data dapat di download di CAIS dan dibuka dengan password " & taskAwait.Item2("strPassword").ToString & "."
                    EmailNotification(strMessage, taskAwait.Item2("strEmail").ToString)
                End If
            Next


            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError("Modul Main" & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Function
 End Module
```

When It hit function **AktivitasTeller.Main(dr)** , it will run only one line after that apps will stoped without entering exception.

ProsesData()

```
Async Function ProsesData(ByVal dr As DataRow, ByVal isAktelFinishProses As Integer) As Task(Of Tuple(Of String, DataRow))
    Try
        If isAktelFinishProses = 0 Then
            Dim result = Await Task.Run(Function() AktivitasTeller.Main(dr))
            If result.ToString = "Success" Then
                ProsesDataAA(dr)
                Return Tuple.Create("success", dr)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Task AT Failed")
                Return Tuple.Create("failed", dr)
            End If
        Else
            ProsesDataAA(dr)
            Return Tuple.Create("success", dr)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError("Modul Proses Data" & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        Return Tuple.Create("failed", dr)
    End Try

End Function
```

AktivitasTeller.Main()

```
Module AktivitasTeller


Async Function Main(ByVal dataRowAktel As DataRow) As Task(Of String)
    Dim strConn As String = GetConn(Conn.eOperasional)
    Dim busOtomasi As New BusOtomasiSample
    Dim bitPlusKCP As Boolean = False
    Dim strcabang As String = ""
    Dim datediff As Integer = 0
    Try
        Dim tasks = New List(Of Task(Of String))()
        busOtomasi.UpdateIsAktelFinishProses(strConn, 2, dataRowAktel("intIDProses"))
        datediff = GetMonthDifference(dataRowAktel("param_datPeriodeAwal"), dataRowAktel("param_datPeriodeAkhir"))

        If dataRowAktel("param_strKcpCd").ToString = "" Then
            bitPlusKCP = True
            strcabang = dataRowAktel("param_strKcuCd").ToString
        Else
            strcabang = dataRowAktel("param_strKcpCd").ToString
        End If

        busOtomasi.DeleteDataAktel(strConn, dataRowAktel("intIDProses").ToString)
        For j = 0 To datediff
            Dim k = 0 + 1
            tasks.Add(AddAktelToSQL(dataRowAktel("intIDProses"), strcabang, CDate(dataRowAktel("param_datPeriodeAwal")).AddMonths(j), CDate(dataRowAktel("param_datPeriodeAwal")).AddMonths(datediff + k).AddDays(-1), bitPlusKCP))
        Next

        Dim t As Task = Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(Sub() GET_CITIZENSHIP_DESC(dataRowAktel("intIDProses")), Sub() busOtomasi.UpdateIsAktelFinishProses(strConn, 1, dataRowAktel("intIDProses")))
        Await t
        If t.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then

            Return "Success"
        Else
            Return "Failed"
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Failed"
    End Try
End Function

Public Function GetMonthDifference(ByVal startDate As DateTime, ByVal endDate As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim monthsApart As Integer = 12 * (startDate.Year - endDate.Year) + startDate.Month - endDate.Month
    Return Math.Abs(monthsApart)
End Function

Async Function AddAktelToSQL(ByVal idProses As Integer, ByVal strCbg As String, ByVal tglAwal As Date, ByVal tglAkhir As Date, ByVal bitPlusKCP As Boolean) As Task(Of String)
    'Dim tblAktelLog As New DataTable

    Dim strConn As String = GetConn(Conn.eOperasional)
    Dim objBusOtomasi_Script As New BusOtomasiSample
    Dim DtTblSaving As New DataTable
    Dim DtTblChecking As New DataTable
    Dim DtTblDeposito As New DataTable
    Dim DtTblRupa2 As New DataTable

    Dim dtCekDeposito, dtCekSaving, dtCekChecking, dtCekRupa As New DataTable
    Try

        'RUPA
        dtCekRupa = objBusOtomasi_Script.CekRupaBulanAtSudahProses(strConn, idProses, tglAwal.Month, tglAwal.Year, strCbg, bitPlusKCP)
        If dtCekRupa.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            DtTblRupa2.Clear()
            DtTblRupa2 = await GetDtTbleRupa(idProses, tglAwal, tglAkhir, strCbg, bitPlusKCP)
            objBusOtomasi_Script.BulkCopyRupaRupa(strConn, DtTblRupa2)
        End If

        'DEPOSITO
        dtCekDeposito = objBusOtomasi_Script.CekBulanAtSudahProses(strConn, idProses, tglAwal.Month, tglAwal.Year, "DEPOSITO", strCbg, bitPlusKCP)
        If dtCekDeposito.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            DtTblDeposito.Clear()
            DtTblDeposito = await GetDtTbleDeposito(idProses, tglAwal, tglAkhir, strCbg, bitPlusKCP)
            objBusOtomasi_Script.bulkCopyAktTel(strConn, DtTblDeposito) 'import Deposito
        End If

     


        Return "Success"
    Catch ex As Exception
        'objBusOtomasi_Script.DelAktelbyID(strConn, idProses)
        EmailError(ex.ToString)

    Finally

        strConn = Nothing
    End Try
End Function


Async Function GetDtTbleDeposito(ByVal idProsesAktel As Integer, ByVal TglAwal As Date, ByVal TglAkhir As Date, ByVal KdCbg As String, ByVal FlagPlusKCP As Boolean) As Task(Of DataTable)
    Dim strDWH As String
    Dim objOraConn As New OracleConnection(GetConn(Conn.DWH))
    Dim objOraComm As New OracleCommand
    Dim objDtTableDeposito As New DataTable
    Dim oraAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
    Try
        strDWH = "select * from ***"
    
        Await objOraConn.OpenAsync()
        
        oraAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(objOraComm)
        objDtTableDeposito = New DataTable
        oraAdapter.Fill(objDtTableDeposito)
        objOraConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return objDtTableDeposito
End Function
Async Function GetDtTbleRupa(ByVal idProsesAktel As Integer, ByVal TglAwal As Date, ByVal TglAkhir As Date, ByVal KdCbg As String, ByVal FlagPlusKCP As Boolean) As Task(Of DataTable)
    Dim strDWH As String
    Dim objOraConn As New OracleConnection(GetConn(Conn.DWH))
    Dim objOraComm As New OracleCommand
    Dim objDtTableRupa2 As New DataTable
    Dim oraAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
    Try
        strDWH = "select * from *** "
       

        Await objOraConn.OpenAsync()
       

        oraAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(objOraComm)
        objDtTableRupa2 = New DataTable
        oraAdapter.Fill(objDtTableRupa2)
        objOraConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return objDtTableRupa2
End Function

Private Sub GET_CITIZENSHIP_DESC(ByVal idProses As Integer)
    Dim strConn As String = GetConn(Conn.eOperasional)
    Dim strDWH As String
    Dim objOraConn As New OracleConnection(GetConn(Conn.DWH))
    Dim objOraComm As New OracleCommand
    Dim objDtTableDeposito As New DataTable
    Dim oraAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
    Dim dtData, dtListCust, dtResult As New DataTable
    Dim busOtomasi As New BusOtomasiSample

    Try
        strDWH = "select * from ** "

        dtListCust = busOtomasi.GetCisFromAktel(strConn, idProses)
        If dtListCust.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To dtListCust.Rows.Count - 1
                objOraConn.Open()
                objOraComm = New OracleCommand(strDWH, objOraConn)
              

                oraAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(objOraComm)
                dtData = New DataTable
                oraAdapter.Fill(dtData)
                If dtData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    dtResult.Merge(dtData.Copy)
                End If

                objOraConn.Close()
            Next

            busOtomasi.BulkCopyCustomerAktel(strConn, dtResult)
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Module

What should i do to make this work

Comment: The first method should be declared as `Async Function Proses() as Task`, and you need to show what calls it and how -- You have a weird mix of pseudo async and synchronous method, `Main()` is marked as async when it's not, `ProsesData()` awaits a function call on a condition that, if not met, calls another method that is not awaited etc.

Comment: @Jimi actually i dont want to make Proses() as async, but if i didn't create it as async, I cant use await, while I need it . this is what call Proses() Sub.

Sub Main()
        Proses()
    End Sub

Comment: can u help me to fix this? @Jimi

Comment: Add any further information to the body of the question -- If this is a Console app, you can declare the `Main` entry point as `Async Function Main() As Task`, so you can await (real) async methods -- Is there a good / specific reason to try and make this non-async calls asynchronous in your context? What is happening in the meanwhile? -- Why do you have `Console.ReadLine()` inside `Proses()`? That doesn't belong at all + note that, as it is, after `Task.WhenAll()` returns (supposing the method is awaited correctly), everything is run synchronously

Comment: Console.ReadLine() ==> I forget to delete this..

Comment: this is a console app, I have a lot of module that need to be run, every module will be used to processing big data @Jimi

Comment: @Jimi I just add more explanation in my question hope it will help a little

Comment: Since you keep on changing the code in your question, it appears you don't have a precise idea of what this code should do, when run like that. It looks like you tried to make these non-async methods async because you want to run `Proses()` concurrently instead of sequentially (without any return data, as it stands). But you don't have any async method there. Maybe running these methods synchronously is a better choice. See, e.g., [How to: Write a simple Parallel.ForEach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

Comment: This supposes that the internal methods you're calling work on data providers / services / whatever that can / allow to handle concurrent requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249446/discussion-between-nicky-apriliani-and-jimi).

Comment: Your line `For Each taskAwait In Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` should not compile.  `Task.WhenAll` does not return a list of tasks, it returns one task which completes when all of the set are completed.  If you want to inspect outcomes afterwards, you'll need to have the routines in the tasks update some sort of shared resource (e.g. a `ConcurrentDictionary` or `BlockingCollection` or the like).